# Compiling a library on a 64 bit architecture: Incorrect register `%rax' used with `l' suffix

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, x86-64

I have to compile a library on a 64 bit architecture, anyway I get that error.
The lines of code affected by the error are in assembler, here's an example (they are all very similar):

```
//=== get the index to write ===///
__asm__ __volatile__ ("lock; xaddl %0,%1"
            : "=r" (indexToWrite), "=m" (   indexTable[entityId] )
            : "0" (1), "m" ( indexTable[entityId] ));
```

can you help me out?

I am under linux 64bit (ubuntu) and I am using gcc.

Comment: How about `xaddq` then?

Comment: The `l` suffix is for dwords. `rax` is a qword.

Comment: Would you consider using [the compiler builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) instead of building them yourself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `k` operand modifier to select a 32-bit sub-register: `xaddl %k0,%1`.

The syntax: `xaddl %k0,%k1` is also harmless, since `%1` is mem addr anyway.
The operand modifiers for 8, 16, 32, and 64 bits are `b`, `w`, `k`, `q` respectively.

---

The second `"m"` in the input list seems suspect to me. I might be wrong, but I think it should be:

`"1" (indexTable[entityId])`

With `xadd` I don't suppose it matters, but this would technically be argument `%3` otherwise.
Personally, I'd go with:

```
: "=r" (indexToWrite), "+m" (indexTable[entityId]) : "0" (1)
```

And yes, `"+m"` is perfectly legal. It has been for a long time, and was only recently corrected as a bug in the *documentation* of gcc!